# WPF binding not working in Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, binding, windows-xp

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class TestBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
{
    private static T _instance;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                var instance = _instance ?? (Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

                _instance = instance;
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    // ReSharper disable once StaticMemberInGenericType
    public static object Lock = new object();

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public class Test : TestBase<Test>
{
    private bool _isDone = true;

    public bool IsDone
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDone;
        }
        set
        {
            _isDone = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have this declared in the xaml:

```
<lib:Test x:Key="Test" />
```

And used like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource Test}, Path=Instance.IsDone}"
```

This is working fine on Vista and higher, but not on XP, it just doesn't bind (falls back to the default value). We wish we could ditch XP but this isn't the case. I tried to find a little more information with Snoop but it crashes on all our XP machines. I'm shooting blanks here and run out of ideas so I'm curious if anyone here has any ideas about this problem.

As a workaround I can add something like this to the Test class:

```
public static Test InstanceXP 
{
   get 
   {
       return Instance;
   }
}
```

But this is a terrible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I magically stumbled upon another workaround that does work on Windows XP.

Instead of declaring it in a <...Resources>, use the following notation instead:

```
 {Binding Source={x:Static lib:Test.Instance}, Path=IsDone}
```

This is working correctly on all Windows versions.